# Dependent project has lower .Net framework than its dependency project in same solution

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, tls1.3

I have two projects (A and B) in the same solution.
Project A depends on project B. Is it possible that project A has .net framework 4.5 and Project B has .net framework 4.8?
I have to use TLS1.3 in project B that's why I am using .net framework 4.8 in the project B.

Comment: why don't you try it and see? But in theory you shouldn't have any major issues upgrading both to 4.8

Comment: @ADyson thanks for your response. I tried with the situation I mentioned in my question and it gives me an error of assembly reference even though I added the reference in my project A. 
I just don't want to upgrade my project A to 4.8.

Comment: why not? It's unlikely to cause breaking changes, from 4.5 to 4.8. Realistically I don't think you have any choice - you simply can't use a library which requires a higher version than the runtime of your main project. (If you could, then when you came to execute the code, it wouldn't be able to execute all the stuff in the library, you could easily end up with a crash because some of it might use features which don't exist in 4.5.)

Comment: P.S. this older question mirrors your situation, just with older versions, but the answer is the same: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2772322/5947043